# How to set an image for each row in list in onBindViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, image, list, android-recyclerview

I have a list of invitees. I am using a recyclerview and custom adapter. In this I am getting the photo from contacts by a contactId fetched with contact number.

Now I as set the imageUri to the image view. Only one image is shown to all the rows for which the imageUri is not null. And the position changes as I scroll up and down. Sometimes it shows the image and sometimes it dose not.

I want set the uri as per the position of invitee. How to do this?

Adapter :

```
    public class InviteeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InviteeAdapter.MyViewHolder>{


    private List<Invitee> inviteeList;
    int status;
    Context context;
    Cursor mCursor;

    private ArrayList<Uri> imageArray;
    public String contactId;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView profileImage;

        String mobileNo;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {

            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleName);
            profileImage = (com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventsIcon);

            imageArray = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public String fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID},
                    null, null, null);

            String contactId = "";

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            return contactId;
        }

    }

    public InviteeAdapter(List<Invitee> inviteeList,Context context) {
        this.inviteeList = inviteeList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.invitee_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Uri imageUri;

        Invitee invitee = new Invitee();

        invitee = inviteeList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(invitee.getFName()+" "+ invitee.getLName());

        contactId = holder.fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(invitee.getMobile());

        ArrayList<String> contactArray = new ArrayList<>();

        imageUri = getPhotoUri();

        imageArray.add(getPhotoUri());

        contactArray.add(contactId);

        for(Uri  id : imageArray)
        {
            //  imageUri = getPhotoUri();

            if(imageUri!= null) {

                holder.profileImage.setImageURI(id);
            }
            else {

                holder.profileImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_person_black_48dp);

            }

        }

       /* status = invitee.;

        if(status == 0)
        {
            holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

        }

        else {

            holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
        }*/


    }


    public Uri getPhotoUri() {
        try {
            Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId  + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='"
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null,
                    null);
            if (cur != null) {
                if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    return null; // no photo
                }
            } else {
                return null; // error in cursor process
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long
                .parseLong(contactId));
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(person, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return inviteeList.size();
    }

}
```

Can someone help please. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Check this link it will help:
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-listview-with-images-using-recyclerview-and-volley/